# Covering tori, action

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I should find an action of the inregers $Z$ on the cylinder $s^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ whose quotient space is the torus $S^1 \times S^1$.

I know that the circle $S^1$ can be obtained as the quotient of $R$ under the action of the integers $\mathbb{Z}$, the action looks like: $n * x = x+n$.
However I do not understand how does it work.

Action in my homework could look like:

$(x_1, n * x_2 = x_2+n)$, xhere $x_1 \in S^1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}, n \in Z$, I think that $S^1$ will be the same. And $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \simeq S^1 \times S^1$.

Comment: Yes, the action will be $n*(x_1,x_2):=(x_1,nx_2)$.

Comment: Do you agree with my method? :)

Comment: Now after your comment I thing that I understand. I did not know why is there equality $n * x = x+n)$, because I did not see how does it work. But if is there only $n*x$, it looks like union of all points which lie on the same line in \mathbb{R}, but I still can not see $S^1$ in it. What about: $\frac{n * x}{|n*x|}$? Will this action create $S^1$ in the way: $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \cong S^1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do indeed let $\Bbb Z$ act on the $\Bbb R$-factor of your cylinder, leaving the $S^1$-factor alone:
$$
n*(x,y)=(x,y+n)
$$
This turns the $\Bbb R$-factor of your cylinder into $S^1$ when you take the quotient, but doesn't touch the $S^1$ factor. So you end up with $S^1\times S^1$.

We can see this explicitly. Consider the resulting equivalence relation:
$$
(x_1,y_1)\sim (x_2,y_2)\iff \exists n\in\Bbb N:n*(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)
$$
What does the equivalence class of an arbitrary point $(x_1,y_1)$ look like? Well, if we are to have $(x_1,y_1)\sim (x_2,y_2)$, then we must have $x_1=x_2$ (meaning the $S_1$ factor stays unchanged) and we must have $y_1-y_2\in\Bbb Z$, turning the $\Bbb R$-factor into $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\cong S^1$.

Comment: Thank you :) However I do not see in this formula $ n*(x,y)=(x,y+n) $ that  $y_1-y_2\in\Bbb Z$ and why does it mean that $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\cong S^1$?

Comment: @lida If you want a more thorough reasoning, we will have to take this entirely from the ground up. Which is to say, what is your definition of the space $S^1$?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand. $S^1$ is created of point which lie on the circle which radius is one. But how does the equality $y_1 - y_2 \in Z$ create this points?

Comment: @lida It means $z_1$ and $z_2$ lies a whole number of "rounds" apart, meaning they are the same point on the circle. Consider the function $f$ that takes real numbers as input, and maps $y$ to $(\cos(2\pi y), \sin(2\pi y))$. If $y_1-y_2\in \Bbb Z$, then $f(y_1) = f(y_2)$, so they are mapped to the same point on the circle. That makes $f$ a homeomorphism from $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ to $S^1$, showing that those two are essentially the same space.

Comment: Thank you. Now it is clear you have explained it to me nice. Let me have just last question, how is this example connected with complexx analysis? :)

Comment: @lida Not at all, really. Some times people like to say that the circle is a subset of the complex plane rather than the regular $\Bbb R^2$, defined as all possible $e^{it}$ for real numbers $t$. But that's about it, I think.

Comment: Thank you, now it is clear.